# How to rsync files with matching name

Tags: copy, rsync

I am trying to copy files from a server to my local machine using rsync but only the files that contain a certain name e.g. Mendota. It will be fine if the name Mendota was at the end or at the start of the name of the files but it is in the middle, something like this:

model_gcm_Mendota_moreinfo_otherinfo.nc4

I tried this:

```
rsync -auvL --include='**_Mendota_*.nc4' --include='*/' --exclude='*' source destination
```

I added --include='*/' cuz I have various subfolders within the main folder. My problem is that it keeps downloading all the files not only the ones that contain the name Mendota on them. I looked into previous posts with similar problems but don't seem to find the right answer for this case. I would really appreciate your help, since this would save me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it actually "downloads" the excluded files/dirs?

Given you're passing `v` option (verbose), it does print a lot of names (directory tree) but I doubt if it actually transfers them. Trying adding `m` to the switches to avoid that.

If the files are actually transferred, make sure you are not calling an alias. For example check the output of `which rsync`.

Comment: Yes, it is downloading all the files, instead of only the ones I want. I checked on the output of which rsync and it shows me the directory of where my rsync is installed.

Comment: Strange. I just ran you snippet on a sample dir (with several nested dirs) and it worked as expected. What OS are you running? What shell? What's `rsync --version`? And can you share an actual value for `source` and `destination` as little obfuscated as possible?

Comment: Hi, I am using Mac 10.15.7 and rsync 29. I am trying to download the data from a private server that needs password so I cannot share that info. Did you try copying from a folder within your machine to another folder?

Comment: Yes, I tried local source and destination. I'm on Linux but I doubt if it has any effect whatsoever. What's the "source" operating system? Are there any non-alphanumeric characters in the dir/filenames? Anything not [0-9a-zA-Z-_.]? I do remember running into this a few years ago and had to use `s` switch to stop the shell from interpreting them.

Comment: Yes I also doubt is the OS. So the directories are like e.g.: model/gcm-1/future and inside each folder each file has a long name such as: model_gcm1_radata_period_otherinfo_variable_name_timestep_start_end.nc4  in this case name for me is as the example Mendota.

Comment: Interesting. So just to rule out any possible wildcard expansion oddities, can you try the same transfer but building the transfer list using 'find'? eg `find SOURCE -type f -name '*_Mendota_*.nc4' -print0 | rsync -avulm --files-from=- SOURCE DEST`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bahman Movaqar, at the end I tried the following: `rsync -auvL --include='**Mendota**' --include='*/' --exclude='*' source destination` , and it worked. So happy now!